# How to create multiple swiper instance in a react component and control one with the swipe of another?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I have a react component where I need to have multiple carousels that are connected. I am trying to create two swiper instance in a react component and control the slide of one on the slide of another.
I need help in creating multiple swiper instances and use in React.
And control one with the movement of the other.

Comment: Two carousels - Very Easy to control/sync with thumbs: https://swiperjs.com/api/#thumbs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### API / Controller

Use API `controller` (Not a lot of docs/examples out there - For specific answer you should add full-code-example):

**swiper API:**
https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#controller

**Github:** [Github issue: How do I get two swiper instances to control each other? #1738](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/273)

**Example**:

```js
let sliderOne = new Swiper(".slider-one", {
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true
  }
});
let sliderTwo = new Swiper(".slider-two", {
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true
  }
});

sliderOne.controller.control = sliderTwo;
sliderTwo.controller.control = sliderOne;
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #007aff;
}


.slider-two .swiper-pagination-bullet-active{
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.1/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="swiper-container slider-one">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>
<div class="swiper-container slider-two">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
```

### thumbs

Two carousels click/swipe A change B - Very Easy to control/sync with thumbs:

> In addition to Controller component Swiper comes with Thumbs component
> that is designed to work with additional thumbs swiper in a more
> correct way than Controller which is used for syncing two swipers.

https://swiperjs.com/api/#thumbs

**Demo:**

- https://swiperjs.com/demos/300-thumbs-gallery.html

**Demo Source code:**

- https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/300-thumbs-gallery.html

Answer (score 0):

**Demo Using React Component**

**API / Controller**

To demonstrate the synchronization of two Swiper components in React, I've created a demo using the Swiper package lastest version. I've followed the documentation provided on the Swiper website, specifically the section on synchronizing Swipers in React, which can be found at https://swiperjs.com/react#controller

You can view the demo you've created on CodeSandbox by following this link. In this demo, you'll see two Swiper components synchronized to work together seamlessly.

**Demo :** [https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/synchronize-swiper-with-react-dfgpzk](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/synchronize-swiper-with-react-dfgpzk?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A27%2C11)

```js
// Import Swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { Autoplay, Controller, Pagination, Navigation } from "swiper/modules";
// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import "./App.css";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [mainSwiper, setMainSwiper] = useState(null);
  const [childSwiper, setChildSwiper] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div className="swiperWrapper">
      {/* First Swiper */}
      <Swiper
        loop
        spaceBetween={10}
        navigation={true}
        pagination={{ clickable: true }}
        modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay, Controller]}
        className="mySwiper2"
        onInit={setMainSwiper}
        controller={{
          by: "container",
          control: childSwiper,
        }}
      >
        {[...Array(7)].map((_, index) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={index}>
            <div className="sliderItem">{`Main slider Item ${index + 1}`}</div>
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
      {/* Second Swiper */}
      <Swiper
        loop
        spaceBetween={10}
        navigation={true}
        pagination={{ clickable: true }}
        modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay, Controller]}
        className="mySwiper"
        onSwiper={setChildSwiper}
        controller={{
          by: "container",
          control: mainSwiper,
        }}
      >
        {[...Array(7)].map((_, index) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={index}>
            <div className="sliderItem">{`Child slider Item ${index + 1}`}</div>
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```